# Find the value in a loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a form with data filled by ajax post; on form page fields values are loaded correctly but I cannot get loaded value from a function inside the page; here is an example:

```
<input type="text" id="mela">
<div style="border:1px solid black; display:none" id="vv">aaa</div>

<script>
  alert($("#mela").val());
  if ($("#mela").val()) {
    $("#vv").show();
  }
</script>
```

The question is: how can I get "mela" value loaded?

Comment: The code works for me on FF 3.6.8

Comment: Yes the example code work if data are not loaded by ajax

Comment: Can you show the loading function and see if the input fields already got updated before you try to access `mela`?

Comment: I use a general function to load data the unique code that may in some way update field is this working function: 
 $("#scheda_sch :text:not(#mela)").live('click', function()
 {
  $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase()); 
 });

Comment: Would you need to close that input tag? <input type="text" id="mela" />

Comment: @mplungjan: I've tried to add / but it does not worked for me.

Comment: But is that script snippet called *after* `mela` is updated? @mplungjan: Nope: “End tag: forbidden” in [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT).

Comment: @Marcel Korpel The load function is contained in main page, the form with field mela is inside a div loaded in main page; I try to access mela directly from form page may this the problem... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me once. I solved the problem by downgrading (or upgrading?) the JQuery. Why don't you give it a try as well?

Comment: Excuse me William what do you mean for downgrade or upgrade Jquery?

Comment: I simply called jquery in my form loaded page and all works correctly! thanks again William!

Comment: By downgrading, I meant if you are using jquery 1.4.2, try to use 1.4.1 instead. It seems that you have solved the problem anyway :)

Comment: @haltman: Indeed. You have to include jQuery….js in every page.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel I'll add it but It will be interesting to understand why all other loaded page with code inside works without jquery included codeing mystery LOL thanks again! ciao
h

Answer (score 1):

If the value is loaded via AJAX, the safest way to ensure that the new value is accessible is to access it *from within* a callback for the AJAX request.

If you're using jQuery `.load()` method, it can accept a callback that executes when the request is `complete`.

```
$('someElement').load('/some/path', function() {
    alert($("#mela").val());
    if ($("#mela").val()) {
        $("#vv").show();
    }
});
```